# If checkbox is checked, trigger click

Tags: jquery, html, forms

What I'm trying to achieve is a checkbox that if it is checked then it triggers a jquery event where a button with id paybox-button when clicked also clicks the button with id mc-embedded-subscribe

The jQuery I have come up with is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#notifyme').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $("#paybox-button").bind("click", (function () {
    $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").trigger("click");
    }));
    }
});
</script>
```

The HTML I have is

```
<a class="paybox-button" href="#" id="paybox-button" onclick="return    paybox_continue(this);">'.__('Continue', 'paybox').'</a>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="display: none;" />
<input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="c62e5af6c6" checked id="notifyme"> Check this box to be notified by email when we publish new content.<br />&nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: What’s not working?

Comment: Please explain your problem in some more details.

Comment: Sory, but I don't understand your problem. Can you provide jsfiddler and more complex explanation of your problem?

Comment: Also, what version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7

Answer (score 0):

`live` has been deprecated (JQuery 1.7)

`bind` has been deprecated (JQuery 3.0)

Change it to this:

```
$('#notifyme').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $("#paybox-button").on("click", (function () {
          $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").trigger("click");
       }));
    }
    else
    {
      $('#paybox-button').off('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: You really should namespace an event like this, in case there are any other click handlers for `#paybox-button`. See my solution

Comment: @mhodges This could be that my knowledge of jQuery isn't where it should be, but in what case would there be multiple click event handlers for the same ```ID```? I total understand (and honestly didn't know you could namespace it out) if it were a class or something other than an ```ID``` that he/she was targeting.

Comment: @James The reasons for having multiple click handlers on a single element are limitless. Everything from 3rd party libraries and complex controlled event propagation to the scenario that someone (or you) edits your code down the road and doesn't notice that a click handler is already registered and sets up a new one to do something different. Namespacing events that you plan to remove is always the safest practice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? It triggers the click event on the `#mc-embedded-subscribe` when you click on the `#paybox-button` while the checkbox is checked, which is how I interpreted what you're trying to do.

Side note - using `onclick=` as well as jQuery click handlers gets messy in a hurry. As a result, I have removed the `onclick` attribute from your `#paybox-button`

```js
$(function () {
  function handleChange ($trigger) {
    if($trigger.is(':checked')){
      // namespace the event so we can .off() it very easily
      $("#paybox-button").on("click.notify", (function () {
        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").trigger("click");
      }));
    }
    else {
      // remove the namespaced event handler
      $("#paybox-button").off("click.notify");
    }
  }
  handleChange($("#notifyme"));
  
  $('#notifyme').on('change', function(){
    handleChange($(this));
  });
  // set up dummy event handler so we know when the hidden button
  // gets clicked
  $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").on("click", function () {
    alert("subscribed!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="paybox-button" href="#" id="paybox-button">'.__('Continue', 'paybox').'</a>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="display: none;" />
<input name="_mc4wp_lists[]" type="checkbox" value="c62e5af6c6" checked id="notifyme"> Check this box to be notified by email when we publish new content.<br />&nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: Hey there your solution works perfect though my issue is that the checkbox is checked by default so it doesn't really work if the user doesn't directly click the checkbox 

I tried modifying to this but no luck 

   $(function () {
    if(document.getElementById('notifyme').checked) {
      $("#paybox-button").on("click.notify", (function () {
        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").trigger("click");
      }));
     }

Comment: @AaronFernandes Check my updated solution. It should work for you if you need your checkbox checked by default